# Square Connect API v2: How to create charge for split tender?

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, payment, square-connect

I'm working on payments integration using square. Square app allows merchants to accept multiple forms of tender(using cards and cash) for single transaction. But, I couldn't find any Endpoint in the [API documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2) to do so. Is there a way to do it or the API only allows us to make card transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out today! Unfortunately, Split Tender isn’t currently available for Square’s API. We currently only support creating single tender payments through our APIs, and those tenders can only be card tenders.

We are constantly improving the product based on feedback like this and would like to know more about your specific use case. If you could email us with more information at developerfeedback@squareup.com our API team would like to here your feedback.

Definitely let me know if you have additional questions or suggestions. I’m happy to help.